# Swift 1.2: Implement optional property from Objc protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, properties, protocols, option-type

Just trying to get started with Swift and hit the following issue when upgrading to Swift 1.2:

```
@protocol MyObjcProtocol <NSObject>
@optional
@property (copy) NSString *optionalString;
- (void) optionalMethod;
@end
```

...

```
class MySwiftClass: NSObject {}

extension MySwiftClass: MyObjcProtocol {
  var optionalString: NSString {
    get { return "Foo" }
    set(newValue) { NSLog("Whatever") }
  }

  // No problem here
  func optionalMethod() {
    NSLog("Bar")
  }
}
```

The Swift extension implementing the Objc protocol doesn't compile with:

> Objective-C method 'optionalString' provided by getter for
>   'optionalString' conflicts with optional requirement getter for
>   'optionalString' in protocol 'MyObjcProtocol'...
>
> Objective-C method 'setOptionalString:' provided by setter for
>   'optionalString' conflicts with optional requirement setter for
>   'optionalString' in protocol 'MyObjcProtocol'...

So clearly the compiler doesn't realise I'm trying to implement the optionals from the protocol, and thinks I'm stomping on the protocol's expected ObjC symbols. The optional *method* `func optionalMethod()` compiles just fine, however. Remove `@optional` from the protocol and everything compiles just fine, but it's not always possible or desirable to do that as a solution.

So, how does one implement this? Trying to implement the expected ObjC methods explicitly doesn't work either:

```
func optionalString() {
  return "foo"
}
func setOptionalString(newValue: NSString) {
  NSLog("")
}
```

Hope someone can help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`MyObjcProtocol` protocol is translated to Swift as:

```
protocol MyObjcProtocol : NSObjectProtocol {

    optional var optionalString: String! { get set }
    optional func optionalMethod()
}
```

So you can just use `String` instead of `NSString`.

```
extension MySwiftClass: MyObjcProtocol {
    var optionalString: String {
        get { return "Foo" }
        set(newValue) { NSLog("Whatever") }
    }

    func optionalMethod() {
        NSLog("Bar")
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. How do you see the Swift translation?

Comment: @DuncanC Made a Framework, `import` it, and command + click :)

Comment: Nice tip. A bit fiddly to do, but I guess won't have to do it once I learn how these kinds of things are translated

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that the protocol requires a stored property because it's specified `copy`, but the swift extension cannot have storage for a property

Comment: The implementation I put here should be ignored: it's trying to implement the optional property as a `var` that's the problem as far as the compiler is concerned. Something like `class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
  var _optionalStorage: NSString?
}

extension MySwiftClass: MyObjcProtocol {
  var optionalString: NSString {
    get { return _optionalStorage! }
    set(newValue) { _optionalStorage = newValue }
  }
}` Emits the same warnings

Comment: yes, but you cannot implement the protocol in the extension, since you require a `copy` property. If you change that to `weak` then it's possible

Comment: Ok. That was more for example I guess. Seems that same extension-can't-provide-storage "limitation" as ObjC. But anyway, main problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Optional properties in Objective C is equivalent to Optional Type in Swift. So it would translate like this:

```
var optionalString: String! // = false
```

in case it can be nil:

```
var optionalString: String? // = nil
```